# Error make: *** with g++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, makefile, g++

Since this morning I get the following error in my C++ project:
**make: *** [myproject] Error 1**.
I'm building with Eclipse on Raspbian Stretch.
The error is related to the whole project, not only the code.
Did I break g++ or something?

**EDIT:**
My main() is empty:

```
#include "ClassesSocket/ServeurSocket.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //ServeurSocket *serveur = new ServeurSocket(25565);


    /*char* status = serveur->start();
    cout << status << endl;

    string message = serveur->recevoirMessage(socketCommunication);
    cout << message << endl;*/

    //delete serveur;
    //serveur = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us more output. Make's Error 1 means "some command failed" and this can't be used to debug a problem.

Comment: Given the information you provide, this is not reproducible or diagnosable.

Comment: That's not the only message from `make`.  If Eclipse is hiding the rest, you'll have to run it yourself.

Comment: What happens if you remove the #include?

Comment: @NieDzejkob Same.

Comment: @Mickrosoft There should be a tab with the errors as one textfield. If there is, what does it say?

Comment: The tab "Problem Details" only says this : _make: *** [ServeurSocket] Error 1 ServeurSocket _ ...

Comment: I built it manually with g++ and I got _collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status_. I'ts weird because I dont have any errors before.

Comment: Ok so i found the problem: a virtual function wasn't written in the cpp file...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have a `main()` in your files, or maybe undefined `myproject`.

Please share the code screenshot or snippet describing the problem.

**Simmiler problem:** 
*C++ does make "name mangling" to allow several functions with the same 
name differing only in return and parameter types. More at

[Eclipse Community Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/279366/)*

Comment: I do have a main(). Actually the problem appeared suddenly.

Comment: @NieDzejkob I don't.

Comment: @MickaëlDebalme Does eclipse show any errors in the error view?